How to implement a two-phased digital signing process with ESP in a distributed system?
I'm implementing a two-phased digital signing process using an ESP (eSign Provider) to digitally sign documents. Here's the process:
Phase 1:

Generate a hash of the document.
Encrypt the hash using the private key of the ESP.
Create a signing request that redirects to the ESP's authentication page (UIDAI-based authentication happens here).

Phase 2:
Receive the signature bytes from another endpoint provided by the ESP.
I have the following challenges:
Keeping PdfSignatureAppearance Object Alive
Since signing occurs in two phases, I need to keep the PdfSignatureAppearance object active until the signing is complete.
Certificate Insertion Issue
When trying to insert the certificate from the ESP response, signature become invalid when checked in adobe
Invalid signature: Document is modified."

Additionally, I want to write this service in a manner that is suitable for a distributed system.
Code for generating hash:
public String pdfSigner(File file, HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
    String hashDocument = null;
    PdfReader reader;
    try {
        String sourcefile = file.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println("Path--->" + sourcefile);
        destFile = sourcefile.replace(file.getName(), "Signed_Pdf.pdf");
        request.getSession().setAttribute("fileName", "Signed_Pdf.pdf");
        reader = new PdfReader(sourcefile);

        Rectangle cropBox = reader.getCropBox(1);
        Rectangle rectangle = null;
        String user = null;
        rectangle = new Rectangle(cropBox.getLeft(), cropBox.getBottom(), cropBox.getLeft(100), cropBox.getBottom(90));
        fout = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, fout, '\0', null, true);

        appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance.setRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION);
        appearance.setAcro6Layers(false);
        Font font = new Font();
        font.setSize(6);
        font.setFamily("Helvetica");
        font.setStyle("italic");
        appearance.setLayer2Font(font);
        Calendar currentDat = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("remove 5 min");
        currentDat.add(currentDat.MINUTE, 5); //Adding Delta Time of 5 Minutes....

        appearance.setSignDate(currentDat);

        if (user == null || user == "null" || user.equals(null) || user.equals("null")) {
            appearance.setLayer2Text("Signed");
        } else {
            appearance.setLayer2Text("Signed by " + user);
        }
        appearance.setCertificationLevel(PdfSignatureAppearance.NOT_CERTIFIED);

        appearance.setImage(null);
        //      appearance.setSignDate(currentDat);
        appearance.setVisibleSignature(rectangle,
                reader.getNumberOfPages(), null);

        int contentEstimated = 8192;
        HashMap<PdfName, Integer> exc = new HashMap();
        exc.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, contentEstimated * 2 + 2);

        PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE,
                PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        dic.setReason(appearance.getReason());
        dic.setLocation(appearance.getLocation());
        dic.setDate(new PdfDate(appearance.getSignDate()));


        appearance.setCryptoDictionary(dic);
        //  request.getSession().setAttribute("pdfHash",appearance);
        appearance.preClose(exc);
        // fout.close();
        request.getSession().setAttribute("appearance", appearance);
        // System.gc();
        // getting bytes of file
        InputStream is = appearance.getRangeStream();

        hashDocument = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(is);
        //session=request.getSession();
        //session.setAttribute("appearance1",appearance);
        System.out.println("hex:    " + is.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in signing doc.");

    }
    return hashDocument;

}

Code for embedding signature:
public String signPdfwithDS(String response, HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
    int contentEstimated = 8192;
    try {
      
        String errorCode = response.substring(response.indexOf("errCode"), response.indexOf("errMsg"));
        errorCode = errorCode.trim();
        if (errorCode.contains("NA")) {

            String pkcsResponse = xmlSigning.parseXml(response.trim());
            byte[] sigbytes = Base64.decodeBase64(pkcsResponse);
            byte[] paddedSig = new byte[contentEstimated];
            System.arraycopy(sigbytes, 0, paddedSig, 0, sigbytes.length);
            PdfDictionary dic2 = new PdfDictionary();
            dic2.put(PdfName.CONTENTS,
                    new PdfString(paddedSig).setHexWriting(true));
            //fout.close();
            appearance.close(dic2);
        } else {
            destFile = "Error";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Hash after signing :" + calculateSha256Hash(destFile));
    return destFile;
}

Inserting cert code:
String certString = response.substring(response.indexOf(User_X509_START_TAG), response.indexOf(User_X509_END_TAG))
        .replaceAll(User_X509_START_TAG, "").replaceAll(User_X509_END_TAG, "");
byte[] certBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(certString);
ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(certBytes);
CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance(X_509);
Certificate cert = factory.generateCertificate(stream);
List<Certificate> certificates = List.of(cert);
appearance.setCrypto(null, certificates.toArray(new Certificate[0]), null, null);

Pdf generated without cert
Pdf generated with cert, here i did not create placeholder at first function created it in second function when embedding the signature.
Update:  implemented second approach now getting "there are errors in the formatting or information contained in this signature in adobe"
methods :
    public String pdfSignerV2(Resource resource, ESignParameter eSignParameter) {
    String hashDocument = null;

    try {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(resource.getInputStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        String signPlaceHolder = eSignParameter.getSignPlaceHolder();

        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, baos, '\0', null, true);
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance.setRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION);
        appearance.setAcro6Layers(false);// deprecated

        Coordinate locationToSign = findLocationToSign(reader, signPlaceHolder);
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(locationToSign.getX(), locationToSign.getY(), locationToSign.getX() + (100), locationToSign.getY() + (50));

        Font font = new Font();
        font.setSize(6);
        font.setFamily(FONT_FAMILY);
        font.setStyle(FONT_STYLE);

        appearance.setLayer2Font(font);
        Calendar currentDat = Calendar.getInstance();
        appearance.setSignDate(currentDat);
        appearance.setLayer2Text("Digitally Signed");

        appearance.setCertificationLevel(PdfSignatureAppearance.NOT_CERTIFIED);
        appearance.setImage(null);
        appearance.setVisibleSignature(rectangle,
                locationToSign.getPageNumber(), signPlaceHolder);
        int contentEstimated = 8192;
        MyExternalSignatureContainer container = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(new byte[]{0});

        MakeSignature.signExternalContainer(appearance, container, contentEstimated);


        InputStream is = appearance.getRangeStream();
        hashDocument = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(is);

        MultipartFile dummySignedPdf = new ByteArrayMultipartFile(FILE_NAME, baos.toByteArray());

        String dummyFileStoreId = fileStoreUtil.storeFileInFileStore(dummySignedPdf, "kl");

        eSignParameter.setFileStoreId(dummyFileStoreId);
        stamper.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }


    return hashDocument;

}







public MultipartFile signPdfWithDSAndReturnMultipartFileV2(Resource resource, String response, ESignParameter eSignParameter) {
    try {
        int contentEstimated = 8192;


        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(resource.getInputStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        String pkcsResponse = new XmlSigning().parseXml(response.trim());
        byte[] sigbytes = Base64.decodeBase64(pkcsResponse);
        byte[] paddedSig = new byte[contentEstimated];
        System.arraycopy(sigbytes, 0, paddedSig, 0, sigbytes.length);
        MyExternalSignatureContainer container = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(paddedSig);

        MakeSignature.signDeferred(reader, eSignParameter.getSignPlaceHolder(), baos, container);

        return new ByteArrayMultipartFile(FILE_NAME, baos.toByteArray());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}

Sign doc with above code signpdf

"When trying to insert the certificate from the ESP response, I encounter the error:" - By certificate do you mean the signer X.509 certificate? But I don't see you handling such a certificate anywhere.

sorry,wrong wording error means signature is not valid when checked in adobe.

shared code embed the valid signature

Can you share (for analysis) an example PDF signed by your code, illustrating the issue

@mkl please find added pdf links ,previously i was creating signature placeholder (in signPdfwithDS function ) after generating the hash , since i want to support distributed system and dont want to store files on server , but signature was invalid , then move to the above code , now signature is valid but user details is not there ( without cert pdf) also does not support distributed system

"please find added pdf links" - I get a "access denied" for those links.

can you try now

'Update: implemented second approach now getting "there are errors in the formatting or information contained in this signature in adobe"' - It looks like the way you implemented second approach is somehow incorrect. For more details, please share sufficient code and/or the result PDF for analysis.

Analyzing your example files
(reacting to quoted comments)

please find added pdf links

Now the links work.

1728913398584nxHAYXdXhs.pdf - the hash of the signed document bytes is incorrect here.
sign2.pdf - the hash of the signed bytes is correct here.


previously i was creating signature placeholder (in signPdfwithDS function ) after generating the hash , since i want to support distributed system and dont want to store files on server , but signature was invalid

That cannot work: If you want any decent PDF signature validator to positively validate your signature, you need to hash the prepared PDF (with signature dictionary containing the placeholder), not something else, because validators expect that the signed byte ranges encompass exactly everything except the placeholder itself.

then move to the above code , now signature is valid but user details is not there ( without cert pdf) also does not support distributed system

Yes, this in principle is how you have to implement signing. There are some options to make this work better in a distributed system, see below.
If you want the signature appearance to contain user details, though, you have to know these user details in preparation phase before signing. If retrieving them from the signature is the only option you have, you may have to create two signatures: The first one for dummy data to extract user details from the signature, the second one for the PDF prepared with those user details.
Making this work in a distributed system
There are two alternatives to Keeping PdfSignatureAppearance Object Alive. Instead of keeping that object alive in a session:

You can duplicate the PDF preparation step; i.e. after preparing the PDF for signing and calculating its hash in step 1, you throw that prepared PDF away. And in step 2 you again start with the original PDF, prepare it, and inject the signature into it.
The challenge here is to make sure that both prepared PDFs are byte-wise identical. This requires you to use the same parameters in doing so, and not only the same explicit parameters you already control but also the same implicit parameters like the system time (which is stored in metadata in the PDF and, therefore, part of the signed data) and the revision ID. In case of encrypted PDFs you may even have to control random number generator seed values, depending on the encryption algorithm used.
Doing this is a bit complicated and requires you to set internal iText values (either by introspection/reflection or by patching iText. Nonetheless, some signing services do so, e.g. the EU eSig DSS example implementation.

You can "sign" the prepared PDF in the first step with some dummy value, and return this dummy-signed PDF with the hash to the caller. In the second step the caller needs to send you both the dummy-signed PDF and the signature for the hash, and you then simply replace that dummy value in the dummy-signed PDF by the provided signature.
You have tagged your question itext5, so I assume you use a current  iText 5 version, i.e. a 5.5.x one, even though your code only makes use of pre-5.3.x features.
iText 5.5.x contains an explicit method to replace the signature value of the outermost signature of a PDF: MakeSignature.signDeferred:
  /**
   * Signs a PDF where space was already reserved.
   * @param reader the original PDF
   * @param fieldName the field to sign. It must be the last field
   * @param outs the output PDF
   * @param externalSignatureContainer the signature container doing the actual signing. Only the 
   * method ExternalSignatureContainer.sign is used
   * @throws DocumentException
   * @throws IOException
   * @throws GeneralSecurityException 
   */
  public static void signDeferred(PdfReader reader, String fieldName, OutputStream outs, ExternalSignatureContainer externalSignatureContainer) throws DocumentException, IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

The reader has to contain the dummy-signed PDF, fieldName needs to be the name of the signature field you created, and externalSignatureContainer can be an instance of a simple ExternalSignatureContainer implementation whose sign method merely returns the provided signature and whose modifySigningDictionary method does nothing.


PS: Implementing option 2
You tried to implement the second option above but ran into another issue:

implemented second approach now getting "there are errors in the formatting or information contained in this signature in adobe"

Analyzing the example file you provided for this, it turned out that the error message in Acrobat actually continues to say

(support information: SigDict /SubFilter value)

and indeed, the signature dictionary in your file contains no Filter and no SubFilter values. These (in particular the latter) are necessary, though, to identify the signature type used.
I assume that the cause for this is that your MyExternalSignatureContainer class has an empty modifySigningDictionary method.
I myself said above that the ExternalSignatureContainer implementation used for signDeferred in modifySigningDictionary may do nothing, but that only is true for use in signDeferred! Your code apparently uses the same ExternalSignatureContainer implementation for signExternalContainer, but here modifySigningDictionary must not be empty, it has to set the Filter and SubFilter!
For signExternalContainer you can use an instance of the iText class ExternalBlankSignatureContainer instead. In its constructor you set the Filter and SubFilter names you want. According to your initial approach you want the Filter PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE and the SubFilter PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED.

thank u @mkl , will try to implement second approach, thank u so much again.

MyExternalSignatureContainer container = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(new byte[]{0}); MakeSignature.signExternalContainer(appearance, container, contentEstimated); here im creating dummy pdf , but MakeSignature.signDeferred not able to replace with actual signature

once i create this dummy signature and hash , i store this file in cloud and retrieve when i get signature byte

"MakeSignature.signDeferred not able to replace with actual signature" - You mean, it is not able because the result shows the error visible in your screenshot? Or not able because an exception is thrown or something like that?

no exception @mkl

added method implementation , please point out if im doing something wrong

Can you also share an example result PDF? That would help to analyze.

added sign pdf with above code

@Prasanna Ok, thanks. In Acrobat here the error message is longer, and that extra indicates the issue. See the edit of my answer.

thank u, its working fine now
